# Drone Geometrical Shape

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mathematics, geometry

[Drone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_aerial_vehicle)

Can Drones be designed with geometrical shapes viz Kite, Cylinder, Sphere etc?

Comment: You can attach motors to a brick - not aerodynamic though.

Comment: what leads you to believe that it may not be possible?